# Visual Studio 2017 'Build' menu option no longer available

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017. When I right-click on any project within my solution, the 'Build' menu option no longer displays. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same problem after update VS. Reopen the solution helped me.

Answer (score -1):

When I clicked on the "Solutions and Folders" dropdown list and selected my solution again, the build option became available again.